# this.props.relay.forceFetch() error: Cannot read property 'getHostNode' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, relayjs, relay

I have a page component that I need to be fetched from server every time it is loaded, guaranteeing fresh data.

Here is my component code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { createFragmentContainer, 
         graphql } from 'react-relay';

import Listing from '../Listing/Listing';

class Page extends Component {

    componentWillMount = () => {

        this.props.relay.forceFetch();
    }

    render = () => {

        return (
                <Listing
                    data={this.props.viewer.users}
                />
            );
     }
 };

export default createFragmentContainer(Users, graphql`
    fragment Users_viewer on Viewer {
        users {
            name
            username
            email
        }
    }`
);
```

When the component is loaded, I´m getting the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getHostNode' of null
    at Object.getHostNode (ReactReconciler.js:62)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.getHostNode (ReactCompositeComponent.js:383)
    at Object.getHostNode (ReactReconciler.js:62)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.getHostNode (ReactCompositeComponent.js:383)
    at Object.getHostNode (ReactReconciler.js:62)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._updateRenderedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:755)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._performComponentUpdate (ReactCompositeComponent.js:723)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.updateComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:644)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performUpdateIfNecessary (ReactCompositeComponent.js:560)
    at Object.performUpdateIfNecessary (ReactReconciler.js:156)
    at runBatchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:150)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.perform (ReactUpdates.js:89)
    at Object.flushBatchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:172)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.closeAll (Transaction.js:209)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:156)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62)
    at Object.enqueueUpdate (ReactUpdates.js:200)
    at enqueueUpdate (ReactUpdateQueue.js:24)
    at Object.enqueueSetState (ReactUpdateQueue.js:218)
    at ReactRelayQueryRenderer../node_modules/react/lib/ReactBaseClasses.js.ReactComponent.setState (ReactBaseClasses.js:64)
    at onError (ReactRelayQueryRenderer.js:196)
    at onRequestError (RelayNetwork.js:86)
    at <anonymous>
```

BTW: This page component is being called using React Router V4.

How to solve that issue and guarantee that the page will get fresh data from server on reload ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `createFragmentContainer` I recommend using `createRefetchContainer`. The name is a bit misleading. It is a component that handles refetching and the original fetch. It should be similar to

```
export default createRefetchContainer(Users, graphql`
    fragment Users_viewer on Viewer {
        users {
            name
            username
            email
        }
    }`,graphql`
        query PageQuery {
        viewer {
            ...Page_viewer
            }
        }
     `
    );
```

Notice that `createRefetchContainer` takes three parameters instead of the two you are used to in createFragmentContainer. Your error is saying that that specific prop is not available because you did not set up a "refetch container." Therefore, it cannot find the relevant component (i.e. node) to update.

Then it will load the data on load. If you want to refetch the data, call `this.props.relay.refetch({}, null, ()=> console.log('refetch done'), {force: true})` in `componentDidMount().` This will be a cleaner, safer, and better performing

Comment: You will not have the ability to use the refetch props (or forceRefetch) for that matter if you do not write a createRefetchContainer.  Setting `{force: true}` is forcefully refetching data.